# Round To 1dp gives wrong number

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, rounding

How do you round a column to 1dp?

```
df value 
0 0.45
1 0.45

df.value.round(1)
0.4
0.4
```

Comment: What is desired result?

Comment: The correct answer is 0.5

Comment: @asd You're using binary floating-point, which means what you see is not what you get. The actual value being rounded is `0.450000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125`. In this particular case, you're correct that that should round to `0.5`, but for example correct rounding would also round `0.85` (with real value `0.84999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375`, assuming IEEE 754 binary64 floating-point format and semantics) to `0.8`, not `0.9`. If your application cares about the rounding direction for these near-halfway cases, you need to re-evaluate your use of floats.

Answer (score 1):

You might harness python built-in `round` to get desired result following way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[0.45,0.45]})
df['rounded'] = df.value.apply(lambda x:round(x,1))
print(df)
```

output

```
   value  rounded
0   0.45      0.5
1   0.45      0.5
```

Difference between `pandas.Series.round` and built-in `round` is bit surprising for me, but might be explained by fact that there are more than one way to round number. This is not limited to `python` only - for example [GNU AWK manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Setting-the-rounding-mode.html) describe 5 different *Rounding modes*.

Comment: Unfortunately, while this happens to "work" for the value `0.45`, this isn't a good approach in general. For example, `round(0.25, 1)` will give `0.2`, which almost certainly isn't what the OP wanted. The real answer starts with a better understanding of floating-point and a question (for the OP to answer) of exactly *why* an answer of `0.4` is problematic to them.